# wireless device not getting PHY address

Tags: linux, airmon-ng

I have the TP Link tl-wn822n ver. C (realtek chipset) wireless adapter and I am running Kali Linux from a live cd. After many hours trying to get around these problematic drivers, I managed to get them to work.

#### Issues

- So now I can connect to the internet, but when I run the `airmon-ng` command the interface of the adapter does not show up.
- When I run the `airmon-zc` command I get the interface as `wlan1` but the `PHY` field is null so I can't get a monitor interface with `airmon-ng start wlan1` command.

Any suggestions on how I can assign it manually maybe?

Comment: please read this also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215

Comment: Have you actually [enabled monitor mode](https://nooblinux.com/how-to-enable-monitor-mode-on-tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-v3/) on the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
ifconfig wlan0mon down
iwconfig wlan0mon mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0mon up
```

After you run these commands, `airodump-ng wlan0mon` will work.

Comment: Actually, you just copy-pasted from [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32039368)